# WordPress includes are not working

Tags: php, wordpress

Why is the following not working at all?

```
<?php include( get_template_directory_uri() . 'include/product-search.php'); ?>
```

My includes are in `wp-content/themes/theme/include/`.

I also tried without `_uri` and lots of other options, but I can get includes to work.

It shows up inside `<p></p>` tags in a page, but nothing more than that...

Comment: Where are you adding this content? This won't work if you add it in the WYSIWYG, you should probably add a short code. See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: trying to add search to product page without cluttering the whole text input in wp, and learning that nothing works in wp as it would work in any other platform. didnt really understand anything about that document page either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out you can't add PHP code to your pages in text editor...

Maybe next time, just don't use WordPress, hundreds of random problems and only one needed plugin.